# Virus Attack. Backup drive reads empty while files are not wiped

Tags: anti-virus, data-recovery

I had a virus attack which is preventing me from accessing all my data on both the computer and my backup drive.  When I connect the drive, it still shows as having the files on it but when I open the drive it reads as empty.  Can you please help with a solution.

Comment: Here's a [canonical reference](http://superuser.com/q/100360/4377) on what to do if computer is infected by a virus or a malware

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your machine first.  Virus is hiding files.  Try [Trend Micro's Housecall](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/)

Comment: Malwarebytes, SuperAntiSpyware and ComboFix are my drugs of choice.